# how to apply the same menu css to other pages

Tags: html, css, menu, firebug

In [this store](http://www.contempecado.com/), if you click on the first two links in the menu, after you scroll down the menu changes: it stays at the top of the visible page with a black background. This way the visitor always have access to the menu.

The squarespace theme I'm using allows this to happen only to these first two pages.
If you enter any other menu link and scroll the page down, you will see that the menu doens't do what it does in the first two pages. If you scroll down, the menu stays at the scrolled part of the page.

I'd like to identify the menu CSS which makes changes it and makes it stay at the top of the page with the black background and apply it to all pages.

I'm having a hard time to identify it using FireBug.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just identify the stylesheet use "inspect element". Right click and select it.

For CSS to make it stay at the top, I think position:fixed will work.